# Plotting the complex exponential function and it's period by hand

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading a bit about the exponential function $e_k: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $$e_{k}: x \mapsto e^{i k x}=\cos k x+i \sin k x$$

The period is given by $2\pi/|k|$. I do not have an intuitive understanding of this. It's just a formular in my textbook. By plotting using WolframAlpha I got some understanding. But how does WolframAlpha plot for example $e_{2}: x \mapsto e^{i 2 x}=\cos 2 x+i \sin 2 x$ ? How am I suppose to do this by hand?

Kind regards

Comment: Typically, you resolve a complex valued function into its real part and imaginary part, and plot each of them separately. Here, you have $\Re(e^{i2x}) = \cos(2x)$ and one for $\Im(e^{i2x}) = \sin(2x)$. You can represent this with two 2D plots or one 3D plot. Sometimes, you might also want a plot of the norm of a complex function, but here that's not all that interesting since $|e^{i2x}| = 1$.

Comment: Oh, okay. So one could just plot $\cos(2x )$ and $\sin (2 x)$ in the same coordinate system. To make a 3D plot I would just parametrise it like this: $f(x)=(x, cos(2x),sin(2x))$. How I understood you correctly?

Comment: Exactly! In 2D, you'd label the appropriate lines as "real part" and "imaginary part". In 3D, you'd label the *axes* as "Real Part" and "Imaginary Part"

Comment: @AlkaKadri Thanks :-)  Nice to know this.